# An idea which would reduce small calculations.How to implement it?

Tags: web-applications, web

**If this is a wrong question to pose on this site please let me know.I can't find a better site. I'll be very grateful if you can suggest few sites/forums,to post this question.**

I have an idea & like to see it in action.

I am currently in my 2nd year of Graduation. We get our semester marks on our college website. 
We have around 7 subjects and so 7 rows on the results page. I cropped it to 4 rows in the pic below.

[image]

***The thing is TOTAL of all the subjects & PERCENTAGE aren't displayed on the page .We need to open a calculator on our PC and then manually type in the marks to add them and get our grand total and calculate the percentage.***

*MY IDEA* 
I would like to reduce the trouble in that some what tedious task. 
So, I thought of making something which would get the student his total marks & percentage in a single click without such manual entry work. 
I'd like to design a plugin or an app (i'm not sure how to address that problem).

*MY QUESTION* 
I found some ways of doing this: 
1)Scanning the source code of the page & find the marks. 
2)By a plugin or app. 
*(I'm not sure how to do it!)*

***I would like a window to popup on the page by a single click & that would display the TOTAL MARKS & PERCENTAGE.***

**How can that be solved?? A plugin or anything??** 
People access the site from their PC as well as MOBILE PHONES .So something which is compatible for both devices is good i feel !!! What do u say??Then how to achieve that ??

Another thing I noticed is that upon selecting the marks from the results table, even the subject names are also getting selected , so how to seperate the marks from selected text.(In case if we need to select text in solving the problem).

*My college has around 3000+ students , so quite a good number of students get to use it.*

I'm doing a major in Computer Science , and would love to build it on my own.i know some c,c++,java ,some html/css as of now.I'm interested in learning new things as well to get this done!

**Thanks for reading this! 
I need your help in letting this happen.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, you can achieve this by a simple bash script :

- wget the webpage containing your result table.
- Parse it using some kind of parser to extract the information that you want, in this case your marks and credits.
- Finally you got to define a simple function that does the calculation for you.

Good luck.

Comment: hi @sohphia , thanks for the response.But do I need to use the script every time I need to calculate it.How is it related to the server-side, as the script resides on my PC.Sorry,if i'm wrong,I'm new to all this stuff!